# Showing list to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have retrieved a list of products from the database, from model to controller. Now, I want to display it in the view when the button is clicked. I don't know which HTML element to use to show the list and how do I pass it to the view?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you can pass the `Model` to the `View` by returning your model like:

```
return View(model);
```

Then in your `View` specify your `model` at the top of your file:

```
@model [Model here]
```

Then you could loop through your objects to display them on the page like so:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var product from Model.Products){
   <li>@product.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```